# Possible to limit results returned, yet leave 'pagination' to table?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I am building a php site using jquery and the DataTables plugin. My page is laid out just as it needs to be with pagination working but in dealing with large datasets, I have noticed the server is pulling ALL returned rows as opposed to the 10 row (can be more) limit stated within each 'page'.

Is it possible to limit the results of a query and yet keep say the ID numbers of those results in memory so when page 2 is hit (or the result number is changed) only new data is sought after?

Does it even make sense to do it this way?

I just dont want to query a DB with 2000 rows returned then have a 'front-end-plugin' make it look like the other results are hidden when they are truthfully on the page from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LIMIT clause in SQL has two parts -- the limit and the offset.

To get the first 10 rows:

```
SELECT ... LIMIT 0,10
```

To get the next 10 rows:

```
SELECT ... LIMIT 10,10
```

To get the next 10 rows:

```
SELECT ... LIMIT 20,10
```

As long as you ORDER the result set the same each time, you absolutely don't have to (and don't want to) first ask the database to send you all 2000 rows.

To display paging in conjunction with this, you still need to know how many total rows match your query. There are two ways to handle that --

1) Ask for a row count with a separate query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE ...
```

2) Use the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS hint in your query, which will tell MySQL to calculate how many rows match the query before returning only the 10 you asked for. You then issue a `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` query to get that result.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS column1, column2 ... LIMIT 0,10
```

2 is preferable since it does not add an extra query to each page load.

Comment: I have to disagree slightly. In my experience implementing this in a couple of sites, option 1 for getting the total count is actually preferable. Using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` tickles a variety of MySQL bugs and quirks, including destroying any performance gain from doing the `LIMIT` clause.

Comment: Thanks for your help first off. I am familiar with the LIMIT clause but the issue I am struggling with is how to actually keep those individual records returned in sometime of data variable, especially without requiring any additional page load. The DataTables plugin actually has server-side examples but they appear to be so old and use older sql calls it is almost more frustrating to cypher through them at all (not to mention have issues with datetime formats and json responses). Looks like I'll have to experiment a bit.

Comment: You have two base options. Pull them all with one query, or just a few with a limit. But you can use jQuery's AJAX tools and write a side script on the server that lets you pull more data in as needed so you don't have to reload the page. That is the way my script usually work.